# jqGrid warning dialog

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have some custom toolbar buttons on a jqGrid.  One of them is dependent on a row being selected, just like the built in edit and delete buttons.  When the user clicks on it with no row selected, I want the user to be presented with the same warning dialog they are presented with from the built in Edit or Delete buttons.  That is, I want to reuse the dialog that the grid uses that says:

Warning
Please, select row

Any idea where the grid displays the alert from?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the code could looks like the following

```
var alertIDs = {themodal: 'alertmod', modalhead: 'alerthd', modalcontent: 'alertcnt'};

$.jgrid.viewModal("#" + alertIDs.themodal,
    {gbox: "#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id), jqm: true});
$("#jqg_alrt").focus();
```

where `this.p.id` (or `$.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id)`) can be replaced to the id of the grid. To be more sure that the alert work I do recommend you to use more long code

```
var alertIDs = {themodal:'alertmod',modalhead:'alerthd',modalcontent:'alertcnt'};
if ($("#"+alertIDs.themodal).html() === null) {
    $.jgrid.createModal(alertIDs,"<div>"+$.jgrid.nav.alerttext+
        "</div><span tabindex='0'><span tabindex='-1' id='jqg_alrt'></span></span>",
        {gbox:"#gbox_"+$.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id),jqModal:true,drag:true,resize:true,
        caption:$.jgrid.nav.alertcap,
        top:100,left:100,width:200,height: 'auto',closeOnEscape:true,
        zIndex: null},"","",true);
}
$.jgrid.viewModal("#"+alertIDs.themodal,
    {gbox:"#gbox_"+$.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id),jqm:true});
$("#jqg_alrt").focus();
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Warning.htm) demonstrate the code. It displays the message

[image]

every time when you click on the `"Click me!"` button.

**UPDATED:** [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551247/315935) contains the information how one can use the above dialog in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It describes many option. The simplest version contains only one simple call `this.modalAlert();`. It displays the same alert dialog, which free jqGrid displays internally.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks.  Now to figure out how you figured that out ;)

Comment: Wow, this is working fine. But I want a little change to this. I want to change the text and heading of the message box to display different messages at different instance. How to achieve that??

Comment: @Amit: In the demo are used explicitly `$.jgrid.nav.alerttext` as the text of the message and `$.jgrid.nav.alertcap` as the title. You can either directly replace `$.jgrid.nav.alerttext` and `$.jgrid.nav.alertcap` as another texts or use `$.expend($.jgrid.nav, {alerttext: "new text", alertcap: "new title"});` to change the texts of default alert message.

Comment: hi, I have tried a lot but still not get anything. plz help.
$.extend($.jgrid.nav, { alerttext: message, alertcap: header });
$.jgrid.createModal(alertIDs, "<div>" + $.jgrid.nav.alerttext + "</div><span tabindex='0'><span tabindex='-1' id='jqg_alrt'></span></span>",{gbox: "#gbox_tblDeltaDPSStatusEvaluation",jqModal: true,drag: true,resize: true,caption: $.jgrid.nav.alertcap,top: 100,left: 100,width: 200,height: 'auto',closeOnEscape: true},"","",true);$.jgrid.viewModal("#" + alertIDs.themodal, { gbox: "#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID("#tblDeltaDPSStatusEvaluation"), jqm: true });$("#jqg_alrt").focus();

Comment: @Amit: Sorry, but I don't understand your goal. What you try to do? The ids like `tblDeltaDPSStatusEvaluation` should correspond the `id` of the `<table>`. Moreover `$.jgrid.jqID("#tblDeltaDPSStatusEvaluation")` part of your code is definitively wrong. You should remove `#` or just replace all with `"tblDeltaDPSStatusEvaluation"` only.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I want to show my updation status message and custom heading in the message box. I followed the way you have suggested above. But it shows the default "Warning" message box(text is "Please, select row"). I have tried with the code which i pasted above for your reference. I have also removed the # from $.jgrid.jqID("#tblDeltaDPSStatusEvaluation"), but not working.

Comment: @Amit: `$.jgrid.nav.alerttext` is the text and the `$.jgrid.nav.alertcap` is the title used in the dialog. If you change the texts you need just replace the above default strings with your custom texts. It's recommended to change values from `alertIDs` to have no conflicts with the existing Alert dialog.

Comment: @Amit: You can consider to use `$.jgrid.info_dialog` method to display your custom message.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, thanks a lot. :) info_dialog is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried Oleg's below solution and it's not working for me.
Doing some debug I realised that `$("#"+alertIDs.themodal).html()` was 'undefined' for me, so the if case proposed by Oleg wasn't working properly.
I changed this:

```
if ($("#"+alertIDs.themodal).html() === null) {
```

into this:

```
if ($("#"+alertIDs.themodal).html() === null || $("#"+alertIDs.themodal).html() === undefined) {
```

and is working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.jgrid.info_dialog.call(this,
    "Warning",              // dialog title
    "Please, select row!"  // text inside of dialog
);
```

It worked well for me!

Comment: He asked to use the same alert, which implies the same localized message as the JQGrid default.