# How to show the default alert message in JQGrid while implementing custom buttons?

Tags: jquery

In form editing in jqgrid if we do not select any row for editing an message box show automatically asking to select any row for editing.

I want to show the same message window while doing some custom functions by implementing the custom button in my jqgrid?

Is there any way to call any method or implement any event to show the message window?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve it by the use of following code

```
var alertIDs = {themodal: 'alertmod', modalhead: 'alerthd', modalcontent: 'alertcnt'};
$.jgrid.viewModal("#" + alertIDs.themodal,
{gbox: "#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id), jqm: true});
 $("#jqg_alrt").focus();
```

Comment: For more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959939/jqgrid-warning-dialog