# jqgrid center alert dialog not working even after trying Oleg 's method

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i am trying to center the alertmod dialog on jqgrid. I have tried the answer by Oleg but did not work for me.

[jqGrid warning dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959939/jqgrid-warning-dialog)

The alert happens when a button on pager is pressed (like delete) and a row is not selected.

I have this function setup for the delete, edit, etc dialogs and works fine

```
 jQuery.fn.center = function () {
                this.css("position", "absolute");
                this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
                this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
                return this;
            }
```

I just cant get it to work for this error dialog

This is how i call it on the other dialogs like edit, delete, etc

```
afterShowForm: function (form) {
                        form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you try to center alert inside of `afterShowForm` callback of form editing, but [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method will be not called in case if no row is selected. Instead of that `navGrid` just calls `$.jgrid.viewModal` instead. jqGrid allows you to control position and the size of alert dialog using the following options **of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition)**: `alertwidth` (default value is 200), `alertheight` (default value is "auto"), `alerttop`, `alertleft`, `alertzIndex`.

Alternatively you can replace or "subclass" `$.jgrid.showModal` or `$.jgrid.viewModal` methods to be able to center the dialog *after* it will be shown. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786177/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21588926/315935) for more details.