# free jqgrid - jqGrid warning dialog

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

All,

I'm trying to implement custom warning message like 'Please Select row' when toolbar button[top pager] is pressed. I don't want to use alert!!

I followed one of the examples from Oleg(JqGrid guru atleast to me!!)
i.e.Stackoverflow reference -  [jqGrid warning dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959939/jqgrid-warning-dialog).
Oleg demo reference - http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Warning.htm

All works well if i use the version same as in Oleg demo. BUT if i change the jqGrid version 4.8.0, the same demo not working :(

I used -

```
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

Any idea whether modal usage changed in later version ?

Best Regards,
Sundar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to use the latest version of free jqGrid. It's 4.9.2. You can download it from GitHub or use from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) directly (see here). The corresponding URLs will be

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.9.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.9.2/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
```

and optionally the language file

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.9.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.js"></script>
```

Including of English locale file `grid.locale-en.js` is not required, because it's included now in the main code of free jqGrid (`jquery.jqgrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`).

Before I explain the problems in the old demo I would recommend you to use simplified method `$.jgrid.info_dialog` to create small dialog. The corresponding code could be

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "Click me too!",
    onClickButton: function () {
        $.jgrid.info_dialog.call(this,
            "Warning",              // dialog title
            "Please, select row!",  // text inside of dialog
            "Close",                // text in the button
            { left: 100, top: 100 } // position relative to grid
        );
    }
});
```

The displayed dialog will be like below

[image]

If you want use text elements from locale file then the code could be modified to the following

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "Click me too!",
    onClickButton: function () {
        var $self = $(this),
            alertText = $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "nav.alerttext"),
            alertTitle = $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "nav.alertcap"),
            bClose = $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "edit.bClose");
        $.jgrid.info_dialog.call(this,
            alertTitle, // dialog title
            alertText,  // text inside of dialog
            bClose,     // text in the button
            { left: 100, top: 100 } // position relative to grid
        );
    }
});
```

If you want to display **exactly the same** alert dialog which displays free jqGrid if no row is selected then the code could be especially simple

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "Click me!",
    onClickButton: function () {
        this.modalAlert();
    }
});
```

In the case you can't customize the texts, but the usage is really simple.

If you want to use `createModal` and `viewModal` like in old demo you should understand the following. There are of cause many changes in free jqGrid. The main compatibility problem in the code: one should call `$.jgrid.createModal` by setting `this` to the DOM of the grid. So one have to modify `$.jgrid.createModal(...)` in the old demo to `$.jgrid.createModal.call(this,...)`. The next problem in the old demo very simple. The condition `$("#"+alertIDs.themodal).html() === null` is wrong in the current versions of jQuery and one should better use `$("#"+alertIDs.themodal).length === 0` instead. It's the next main problem in the old demo. The full code could be for example the following

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
    caption: "Click me!",
    onClickButton: function () {
        var $self = $(this),
            p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
            gridId = p.id,
            alertIDs = {
                themodal: "myalertmod_" + gridId,
                modalhead: "myalerthd_" + gridId,
                modalcontent: "myalertcnt_" + gridId
            },
            alertSelector = "#" + $.jgrid.jqID(alertIDs.themodal),
            alertText = $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "nav.alerttext"),
            alertTitle = $self.jqGrid("getGridRes", "nav.alertcap");
        if ($(alertSelector).length === 0) {
            $.jgrid.createModal.call(this,
                alertIDs,
                "<div>" + alertText + "</div>",
                {
                    gbox: p.gBox,
                    jqModal: true,
                    drag: true,
                    resize: true,
                    caption: alertTitle,
                    top: 100,
                    left: 100,
                    width: 200,
                    height: "auto",
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    zIndex: null
                },
                "", "", true);
        }
        $.jgrid.viewModal(
            alertSelector,
            {
                gbox: p.gBox,
                toTop: true
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. After reading your explanation, I'm getting inspiration to learn more about client side technologies which was never in my radar. :)

Comment: @Sundar: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. Many years ago I developed more server side code or system software (like windows services). I could still see that JavaScript and web technologies plays more and more important role. So I started with JavaScript, jQuery and jqGrid in one new project. After some time I found the technology very interesting and I really like there now. I hope that you will soon find there interesting too.